# Python relative imports

Tags: python, import, package, importerror

Right, 
I have a structure like so:

```
/Project
    __init__.py
    script_a.py
    /tests
        __init__.py
        test_something.py
```

When `test_something` tries to import using `from . import script_a` it returns the error `Attempted relative import in non-package`.

I've put in the empty `__init__.py` files and added `/Project` to `PYTHONPATH` but it still throws up this error!

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I have now used a `tester.py` situated in `\Project` and call:

```
import script_a
from tests.test_something import *
```

Now it works!!

Comment: Try something like ```from ../script_a.py import *```

Comment: that is apparently invalid syntax. Did you mean from `from .. script_a import *`? (still doesn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When `test_something` tries to import using `from . import script_a` it returns the error `Attempted relative import in non-package`.

1. Using one dot `.` will lead you to the current directory. You should use two dots `..` to get to the parent dir.
2. You cannot run a module with a relative import itself. You can only import it. So `test_something.py` can only run as an import but it is not possible to run the script as `__main__`

Comment: Ok, but when I import test_something it raises: `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

Answer (score 1):

`from Project import script_a` should work for you.

Comment: Now it says ImportError: No module named Project!!